# Assigning to expression templates

Tags: c++, expression-templates

I have little c++ experience, but now I need to look at some code that uses expression templates a lot, so I am reading chapter 18 of the book << C++ Templates: The Complete Guide >> and working on the example provided in the book. If you happened to have the book, the example starts from pp 328, with all the contextual information.

My code works fine until I want to add the support for subvector indexing (pp 338), I could not get the assignment to work, g++ gives the following error:

```
error: binding ‘const value_type {aka const double}’ to reference of type ‘double&’ discards qualifiers
         return v[vi[idx]];
```

I have no idea what's going on, am I assigning to a constant object? How do I make this work? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template<typename T>
class ET_Scalar {
    private:
        const T& s;

    public:
        ET_Scalar(const T& v) :
            s(v) {}

        T operator[](size_t) const
        {
            return s;
        }

        size_t size() const
        {
            return 0;   // Zero means it's a scalar
        }
};


template<typename T, typename V, typename VI>
class ET_SubVec {
    private:
        const V& v;
        const VI& vi;

    public:
        ET_SubVec(const V& a, const VI& b) :
            v(a), vi(b) {}

        const T operator[] (size_t idx) const
        {
            return v[vi[idx]];
        }

        T& operator[] (size_t idx)
        {
            return v[vi[idx]];
        }

        size_t size() const
        {
            return vi.size();
        }
};


// Using std::vector as storage
template<typename T, typename Rep = std::vector<T>>
class ET_Vector {
    private:
        Rep expr_rep;

    public:
        // Create vector with initial size
        explicit ET_Vector(size_t s) :
            expr_rep(s) {}

        ET_Vector(const Rep& v) :
            expr_rep(v) {}

        ET_Vector& operator=(const ET_Vector& v)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                expr_rep[i] = v[i];

            return *this;
        }

        template<typename T2, typename Rep2>
        ET_Vector& operator=(const ET_Vector<T2, Rep2>& v)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                expr_rep[i] = v[i];

            return *this;
        }

        size_t size() const
        {
            return expr_rep.size();
        }

        const T operator[](size_t idx) const
        {
            return expr_rep[idx];
        }

        T& operator[](size_t idx)
        {
            return expr_rep[idx];
        }


        template<typename T2, typename Rep2>
        ET_Vector<T, ET_SubVec<T, Rep, Rep2>> operator[](const ET_Vector<T2, Rep2>& vi)
        {
            return ET_Vector<T, ET_SubVec<T, Rep, Rep2>>(ET_SubVec<T, Rep, Rep2>(expr_rep, vi.rep()));
        }


        template<typename T2, typename Rep2>
        const ET_Vector<T, ET_SubVec<T, Rep, Rep2>> operator[](const ET_Vector<T2, Rep2>& vi) const
        {
            return ET_Vector<T, ET_SubVec<T, Rep, Rep2>>(ET_SubVec<T, Rep, Rep2>(expr_rep, vi.rep()));
        }


        // Return what the vector currently represents
        const Rep& rep() const
        {
            return expr_rep;
        }

        Rep& rep()
        {
            return expr_rep;
        }
};


template<typename T>
class ET_Traits {
    public:
        typedef const T& ExprRef;
};


template<typename T>
class ET_Traits<ET_Scalar<T>> {
    public:
        typedef ET_Scalar<T> ExprRef;
};


template<typename T, typename LHS, typename RHS>
class ET_Add {
    private:
        typename ET_Traits<LHS>::ExprRef lhs;
        typename ET_Traits<RHS>::ExprRef rhs;

    public:
        ET_Add(const LHS& l, const RHS& r) :
            lhs(l), rhs(r) {}

        T operator[](size_t idx) const
        {
            return lhs[idx] + rhs[idx];
        }

        size_t size() const
        {
            return (lhs.size() != 0) ? lhs.size() : rhs.size();
        }
};


template<typename T, typename LHS, typename RHS>
class ET_Mul {
    private:
        typename ET_Traits<LHS>::ExprRef lhs;
        typename ET_Traits<RHS>::ExprRef rhs;

    public:
        ET_Mul(const LHS& l, const RHS& r) :
            lhs(l), rhs(r) {}

        T operator[](size_t idx) const
        {
            return lhs[idx] * rhs[idx];
        }

        size_t size() const
        {
            return (lhs.size() != 0) ? lhs.size() : rhs.size();
        }
};


// Vector + Vector
template<typename T, typename LHS, typename RHS>
ET_Vector<T, ET_Add<T, LHS, RHS>>
operator+(const ET_Vector<T, LHS>& a, const ET_Vector<T, RHS>& b)
{
    return ET_Vector<T, ET_Add<T, LHS, RHS>>(ET_Add<T, LHS, RHS>(a.rep(), b.rep()));
}


// Scalar + Vector
template<typename T, typename RHS>
ET_Vector<T, ET_Add<T, ET_Scalar<T>, RHS>>
operator+(const T& s, const ET_Vector<T, RHS>& b)
{
    return ET_Vector<T, ET_Add<T, ET_Scalar<T>, RHS>>(ET_Add<T, ET_Scalar<T>, RHS>(ET_Scalar<T>(s), b.rep()));
}


// Vector .* Vector
template<typename T, typename LHS, typename RHS>
ET_Vector<T, ET_Mul<T, LHS, RHS>>
operator*(const ET_Vector<T, LHS>& a, const ET_Vector<T, RHS>& b)
{
    return ET_Vector<T, ET_Mul<T, LHS, RHS>>(ET_Mul<T, LHS, RHS>(a.rep(), b.rep()));
}


//Scalar * Vector
template<typename T, typename RHS>
ET_Vector<T, ET_Mul<T, ET_Scalar<T>, RHS>>
operator*(const T& s, const ET_Vector<T, RHS>& b)
{
    return ET_Vector<T, ET_Mul<T, ET_Scalar<T>, RHS>>(ET_Mul<T, ET_Scalar<T>, RHS>(ET_Scalar<T>(s), b.rep()));
}


template<typename T>
void print_vec(const T& e)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < e.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << e[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return;
}


int main()
{
    size_t N = 16;

    ET_Vector<double> x(N);
    ET_Vector<double> y(N);
    ET_Vector<double> z(N);
    ET_Vector<int> idx(N / 2);

    // Do not use auto z = [expr] here! Otherwise the type of z will still be a
    // container, and evaluation won't happen until later. But the compiler
    // will optimize necessary information away, causing errors.
    z = (6.5 + x) + (-2.0 * (1.25 + y));

    print_vec(z);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        idx[i] = 2 * i;

    z[idx] = -1.0 * z[idx];

    print_vec(z);

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry about its length, I've failed to create a minimal (not) working example.

Comment: In `T& ET_SubVec::operator[] (size_t idx)` you return a non-const reference into const data. The compiler will not allow that.

Comment: @torkel-bjørnson-langen Thanks. I removed the `const` in front of all the `V&` in the ET_SubVec class and it worked. Is this the right way to fix it? Or it is a hack and there are better options?